# Proving $f$ is continuous at $1,-1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Question**: given

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
         x^4 & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$;}\\
        2x^2-1 & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}^c$.}
     \end{cases}
$$

I need to prove that given function continuous only at points $1,-1$

**My attempt** Using sequential criterion of continuity I had proved that, $f$ is 'not' continuous on $\mathbb{R}-\{1,-1\}$.

But, I am facing difficulty in proving $f$ is continuous at points $1,-1$.

I considered, $|f(x)-f(1)|=|f(x)-1|≤sup\{|x^4-1|, |2x^2-1|\}$

How to show this is less than $\epsilon$. Please help me, in proving $f$ is continuous at points $1,-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^4$ is continuous at $1$ we know that for an $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta'$ such that $|x - 1| < \delta' \implies |x^4 - 1| < \epsilon$. Likewise there is a $\delta''$ for $2x^2 - 1$ such that $|x - 1| < \delta'' \implies |2x^2 - 2| < \epsilon$. Now take $\delta = inf(\delta', \delta'')$, then $|x - 1| < \delta \implies |x^4 - 1| < \epsilon$ and $|2x^2 -1| < \epsilon \implies sup\{|x^4 - 1|, |2x^2 -2|\} < \epsilon$. This proves continuity at $1$.